Mozilla Thunderbird on Ubuntu 22.04 keeps opening
Every time I turn on my laptop, Mozilla Thunderbird starts up and overrides any other app or project I try to open.
When I close it, it reopens automatically and blocks the screen.
I’ve tried dpkg and cannot get past Thunderbird to reach the terminal

"cannot get past Thunderbird to reach the terminal" Have you tried to use Ctrl+Alt+→ to open another workspace in which to open terminal?

Most likely you added Thunderbird to startup applications. Open the Startup Applications app and remove Thunderbird.

Would that make it keep opening after being closed?

I tried all of the suggestions so far, and was even able to open Updates, which began downloading and installing the needed updates in spite of Thunderbird opening constantly it opened 12 workspaces at one time. Nothing is in the startup menu, that was the first thing I looked for, and since it couldn’t handle the Thunderbird barrage the system began shutting itself off. Could it have a virus of some type?

eventually the entire system crashed, so I removed the HD and reinstalled it. I was able to enter the recovery mode and used .dpkg That allowed the system to restart but Thunerbird still opens multiple workspaces ... there were 14 at once this time.


Try replacing thunderbird snap with the deb package https://askubuntu.com/a/1513446/124466. 2. Consider fresh installing 24.04.

